# Zero-inflated two-part models in GLMMadaptive (R): anova on fixed effects zero-part?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models

I'm running a hurdle lognormal model using the GLMMadaptive package in R. Both the continuous part as well as the zero-part have categorical variables defined in the fixed effects. I would like to run an ANOVA on these categorical variables to detect if there is a main effect.

I've seen that using the glmmTMB package you are able to separately run an ANOVA on the conditional model and the zero-part model separately, as is demonstrated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474561/how-to-get-p-values-for-the-zero-inflated-part-of-a-model).

Is there a similar strategy available for the GLMMadaptive package? (The glmmTMB does not support hurdle lognormal models as far as I understood). Perhaps using the `joint_tests` function from the emmeans package? If so, how do you define that you want to test the zero-part model? As `emmeans::joint_tests(hurdlemodel)` only gives the F-tests for the conditional part of the model.

Or as an alternative method, could you compare the fit of the models where you exclude the variable of interest against a the full model, as is demonstrated for the relevance of random effects in [this vignette](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html)?

Many thanks!

---

The suggestion by Russ Lenth in the comments are implemented below, using the data and model in the [GLMMadaptive two-part model vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GLMMadaptive/vignettes/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html#two-part-mixed-effects-model-for-semi-continuous-data):

```
library(GLMMadaptive)
library(emmeans)

# data generating code from the vignette:
{
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100 # number of subjects
K <- 8 # number of measurements per subject
t_max <- 5 # maximum follow-up time

# we construct a data frame with the design: 
# everyone has a baseline measurement, and then measurements at random follow-up times
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_len(n), each = K),
                 time = c(replicate(n, c(0, sort(runif(K - 1, 0, t_max))))),
                 sex = rep(gl(2, n/2, labels = c("male", "female")), each = K))

# design matrices for the fixed and random effects non-zero part
X <- model.matrix(~ sex * time, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = DF)
# design matrices for the fixed and random effects zero part
X_zi <- model.matrix(~ sex, data = DF)
Z_zi <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = DF)

betas <- c(1.5, 0.05, 0.05, -0.03) # fixed effects coefficients non-zero part
shape <- 2 # shape/size parameter of the negative binomial distribution
gammas <- c(-1.5, 0.5) # fixed effects coefficients zero part
D11 <- 0.5 # variance of random intercepts non-zero part
D22 <- 0.4 # variance of random intercepts zero part

# we simulate random effects
b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D11)), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D22)))
# linear predictor non-zero part
eta_y <- as.vector(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, 1, drop = FALSE]))
# linear predictor zero part
eta_zi <- as.vector(X_zi %*% gammas + rowSums(Z_zi * b[DF$id, 2, drop = FALSE]))
# we simulate negative binomial longitudinal data
DF$y <- rnbinom(n * K, size = shape, mu = exp(eta_y))
# we set the extra zeros
DF$y[as.logical(rbinom(n * K, size = 1, prob = plogis(eta_zi)))] <- 0
}

#create categorical time variable
DF$time_categorical[DF$time<2.5] <- "early"
DF$time_categorical[DF$time>=2.5] <- "late"
DF$time_categorical <- as.factor(DF$time_categorical)

#model with interaction in fixed effects zero part and adding nesting in zero part as in model above
km3 <- mixed_model(y ~ sex * time_categorical, random = ~ 1 | id, data = DF, 
                   family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,
                   zi_fixed = ~ sex * time_categorical, zi_random = ~ 1 | id)

#### ATTEMPT at QDRG function in emmeans ####

coef_zero_part <- fixef(km3, sub_model = "zero_part")
vcov_zero_part <- vcov(km3)[9:12,9:12]

qd_km3 <- emmeans::qdrg(formula = ~ sex * time_categorical, data = DF,
coef = coef_zero_part, vcov = vcov_zero_part)
```

Output:

```
> joint_tests(qd_km3)
 model term           df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 sex                    1 Inf  11.509 0.0007 
 time_categorical       1 Inf   0.488 0.4848 
 sex:time_categorical   1 Inf   1.077 0.2993 

> emmeans(qd_km3, pairwise ~ sex|time_categorical)
$emmeans
time_categorical = early:
 sex    emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 male   -1.592 0.201 Inf     -1.99    -1.198
 female -1.035 0.187 Inf     -1.40    -0.669

time_categorical = late:
 sex    emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 male   -1.914 0.247 Inf     -2.40    -1.429
 female -0.972 0.188 Inf     -1.34    -0.605

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
time_categorical = early:
 contrast      estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 male - female   -0.557 0.270 Inf -2.064  0.0390 

time_categorical = late:
 contrast      estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 male - female   -0.942 0.306 Inf -3.079  0.0021
```

Checking if contrasts correspond with zero-part fixed effects:

```
> fixef(km3, sub_model = "zero_part")
                   (Intercept)                      sexfemale           time_categoricallate sexfemale:time_categoricallate 
                    -1.5920415                      0.5568072                     -0.3220390                      0.3849780 

> (-1.5920) - (-1.5920 + 0.5568)
[1] -0.5568 #matches contrast within "early" level of "time_categorical"
> (-1.5920 + -0.3220) - (-1.5920 + -0.3220  + 0.5568 + 0.3850)
[1] -0.9418 #matches contrast within "late" level of "time_categorical"
```

Comment: You might be able to use `emmeans::qdrg()` to create the needed object. See its documentation. You clearly will not be able to use the `object` argument. You will need to specify the data, the fixed-effects formula for the conditional or zero part of the model, and the associated regression coefficients and vcov matrix for the part of the model in question. For the latter, you likely will have to pick a subset of the coefficients and covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've been trying it out, but it does not seem to work yet (probably due to my lack of insight...). I've added my code in the post above.

Comment: Looks basically ok. Try listing what you're using for coef and vcov and make sure you don't have extra stuff in there.

Comment: It still doesn't work, though the `vcov` element was indeed not selective for the zero part. I've now edited this to be a 4x4 matrix with row/columsn "zi_(Intercept)" "zi_sexfemale", "zi_time_categoricallate" and "zi_sexfemale:time_categoricallate". The `coef` element is a matrix with 4 columns "(Intercept)", "sexfemale", "time_categoricallate" and "sexfemale:time_categoricallate", and a row for each nest of `id`. Does the naming of the columns matter? Or could there be another issue? Thank  you!

Comment: Why is your coef a matrix? It should be a vector of length 4.

Comment: Yes, this fixes it! See updated code above. Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Yay, glad it worked. Probably a good idea to check that results for "trt.vs.ctrl1" contrasts match the fixed-effect coefficients

Comment: They seem to match! See updated post above! Feel free to submit your suggestions as an answer if you would like the stack overflow reputation points (there is a bounty too) :) Many thanks again!

Comment: When should we use GLMMadaptive instead of lme4 or glmmTMB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `emmeans::qdrg()` can sometimes be used to create the needed object for a model not directly supported by **emmeans**. See its documentation. In very simple models (e.g., inheriting from `lm`, it may be enough to supply the `object` and `data` arguments.

That usually does not work for more sophisticated models, in which case
you will need to specify `data`, the fixed-effects `formula` for the conditional or zero part of the model, and the associated regression coefficients (`coef`) and variance-covariance matrix (`vcov`) for the part of the model in question. Often with models like this with multiple components, you likely will have to pick a subset of the coefficients and covariance matrix. These all must conform: the length of `coef` must equal the number of rows and columns of `vcov` and the number of columns in the model matrix generated by `formula` [which may be checked via `model.matrix(formula, data = data)`].

`qdrg()` will *not* work for a multivariate model -- or at least it's tricky -- because the implied model involves other factor(s) that delineate the levels of the multivariate response. If there are special provisions for, say, spline smoothing, that is another instance where `qdrg()` probably can't be made to work.

Once `qdrg()` actually runs and produces results, it is a good idea to use it to estimate some contrasts that are estimated by the model parameterization. For example, suppose that the model was fitted with the default `contr.treatment` contrasts. Then the regression coefficients are interpretable as a comparison with the first level as a reference level. Accordingly, if we computed`rg <- qdrg(...)`, and one of the factors is `"treat"`, look at `contrast(rg, "trt.vs.ctrl1", simple = "treat")`, and check to see if the *first* set of estimated contrasts matches the main-effect estimates for `treat`.

I will illustrate all of this with a simple `lm` model, ignoring the fact that it is already supported by **emmeans**.

```
> warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
```

Here is the reference grid

```
> rg <- qdrg(~ wool * tension, coef = coef(warp.lm), vcov = vcov(warp.lm),
+     df = df.residual(warp.lm), data = warpbreaks)
```

Here is a sanity check -- First, look at the model summary:

```
> summary(warp.lm)$coef
                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     44.55556   3.646761 12.217842 2.425903e-16
woolB          -16.33333   5.157299 -3.167032 2.676803e-03
tensionM       -20.55556   5.157299 -3.985721 2.280796e-04
tensionH       -20.00000   5.157299 -3.877999 3.199282e-04
woolB:tensionM  21.11111   7.293523  2.894501 5.698287e-03
woolB:tensionH  10.55556   7.293523  1.447251 1.543266e-01
```

Second, look at selected contrasts:

```
> contrast(rg, "trt.vs.ctrl1", simple = "wool")
tension = L:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 B - A      -16.33 5.16 48 -3.167  0.0027 

tension = M:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 B - A        4.78 5.16 48  0.926  0.3589 

tension = H:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 B - A       -5.78 5.16 48 -1.120  0.2682 

> contrast(rg, "trt.vs.ctrl1", simple = "tension")
wool = A:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 M - L     -20.556 5.16 48 -3.986  0.0005 
 H - L     -20.000 5.16 48 -3.878  0.0006 

wool = B:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 M - L       0.556 5.16 48  0.108  0.9863 
 H - L      -9.444 5.16 48 -1.831  0.1338 

P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 2 tests
```

Comparing with the regression coefficients, we do confirm that the first contrast for `wool` is estimated as -16.33, matching the regression coefficient for `woolB`. Also, the first set of contrasts for `tension` are estimated as -20.556 and -20.0, matching the regression coefficients for `tensionM` and `tensionH`. The SEs and *t* ratios match as well. (The *P* values for the second set do not match due to the multiplicity adjustment.)